# Making sqlite3_open() fail if the file already exists

Tags: sqlite, race-condition

I'm developing an application that uses SQLite for its data files. I'm just linking in the SQLite amalgamation source, using it directly.

If the user chooses to create a new file, I check to see if the file already exists, ask the user if they want to overwrite the file, and delete it if they say yes. Then I call `sqlite3_open_v2()` with flags set to `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` to create and open the new data file.

Which is fine, except, what happens if a malicious user recreates the file I'm trying to open in between the file being deleted and SQLite opening it? As far as I'm aware, SQLite will just open the existing file.

My program doesn't involve passwords or any kind of security function whatsoever. It's a pretty simple app, all things considered. However, I've read plenty of stories where someone uses a simple app with an obscure bug in it to bypass the security of some system.

So, bottom line, is there a way to make `sqlite3_open()` fail if the file already exists?

Comment: What would be the difference between a rouge process creating a bogus file before the app is opened vs. creating the file between checking for a file and calling `sqlite3_open()`?  Or what is the difference of impact if such a rouge process were to overwrite an existing file that would be opened later?  If the app has no other way to validate the file other than if it opens or not, is there really any difference in the risk between the various scenarios?

Comment: Probably no difference. But I've read so many bug reports involving a malicious process creating a file that the target program doesn't expect, which causes an obscure bug in the create-new-file function to do Something Bad, that I'd rather be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to patch in support for the O_EXCL option flag of open(2). If you are using SQLite on a platform that supports that.